# Where is histreedit in Zsh?

Tags: zsh

What is the Bash `shopt -s histreedit` equivalent in Zsh ?

FYI from [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

> `histreedit`
>
> If set, and Readline is being used, a user is given the opportunity to re-edit a failed history substitution.

Comment: Related: [How to make Zsh not store failed command](https://superuser.com/questions/902241/how-to-make-zsh-not-store-failed-command)

Comment: See Alt+! or Alt+Space which performs history expansion in-place (and can be undone)

Comment: And the `magic-space` widget which you could bind to Space.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, zsh has no builtin equivalent. You can approximate by doing something like (in `~/.zshrc`):

```
accept-line() {
  pre_HISTCMD=$HISTCMD pre_BUFFER=$BUFFER pre_CURSOR=$CURSOR
  zle .$WIDGET
}

zle-line-init() {
  if (( $? == 1 && HISTCMD == pre_HISTCMD )) && [[ -z $BUFFER ]]; then
    BUFFER=$pre_BUFFER CURSOR=$pre_CURSOR
  fi
}

zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N accept-line
```

Working on the fact that a failed history expansion sets `$?` to `1` and doesn't add an history entry (except when the expansion was added to a historic line it seems; you'll likely find that that trick doesn't work in many corner cases).

Now, IMO, while history expansion (introduced by csh in the late 70s) had its place in the 80s when terminals were slow and line editing was very basic, I for one much prefer using history extraction widgets like history based completions, and things like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and other widgets that extract data from the history.

I've been systematically disabling history expansion in my interactive zsh shells since the late 90s. One of my main issues is that it's not WYSIWYG. It's only after you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that's the expansion is done and the command run at the same time and the pre-expansion code is not saved onto the history.

1. it may fail to expand and you have to redo it again
2. it may expand but to the wrong event, not the one you intended, or the wrong word or type of word if using word designators, or the modifiers not working as expected and you end up running the wrong command.

`histreedit` helps for 1, but not for 2, `histverify` (from zsh 2.1 in 1991, also supported by bash since 2.0 (1996)) helps for 2 but not for 1.

IMO, a better approach is to use the `expand-history` widget, bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by default in `emacs` mode, to perform the expansion explicitly in a WYSIWYG manner to see what you get (and beeps when it fails), and which you can undo with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>, or the `magic-space` widget, not bound by default, but intended to be bound to <kbd>Space</kbd>, which inserts a space and also performs history expansion.